# Could this answer be close to reaching the character limit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, character-limit

Hello, there is currently a very large(and informative!) answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451319/asp-net-mvc-view-engine-comparison/1451355#1451355). It currently has almost 10,000 characters. I remember reading however that the 30,000 character limit is based on the HTML produced by markdown, so this count could actually be considerably higher.

Is this answer close enough to reaching the 30,000 character limit that there is something to worry about? Also, I wish for people to add examples for every view engine listed, probably adding to the character count by 5,000 or 10,000.

Should the character limit be increased? Or should long answers like this be discouraged?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem, to be honest, it is a compilation answer, and as a one-stop reference, it looks like it's useful and appreciated (115 upvotes).